# Walker class: Problems with understanding how walk() method can be called without error

Tags: php, menus, customization, walker

I am struggling with understanding how WordPress uses the Walker class. In particular, I don't understand the `walk()` method (I think).

First, let me explain what I understood:

When calling [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), it's possible to add an array as argument, containing infos/options such as depth, container, theme location, walker to use and so on.

Inside `wp_nav_menu()`, these arguments are merged witch default values. The resulting array (later cast to object) called `$args`.

Inside `wp_nav_menu()`, [`walk_nav_menu_tree()`](http://de.wpseek.com/function/walk_nav_menu_tree/) is called, receiving `$sorted_menu_items`, `$args->depth` and `$args` as arguments.

Until that point I am able to understand what is happening, but inside `walk_nav_menu_tree()`, the [Walker class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) is instantiated, and this is where I can't follow along anymore.

After instantiation, the `walk()` method of the Walker used is called.

According to its signature, `walk()` accepts two arguments: `$elements` and `$max_depth`.

*But in `walk_nav_menu_tree()`, `walk()` gets passed only one argument called `$args`*, which is an array containing the arguments passed to `walk_nav_menu_tree()`, which are actually `$items`(= `$sorted_menu_items`), `$depth` (= `$args->depth`), `$r` (= `$args`).

As if this isn't confusing enough already, at the beginning of the `walk()` method, there is this line:

```
$args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
```

What happens here is using `func_get_args()`, all arguments passed to the method are gathered into an array, from which then the first two parts are omitted, which leaves us with `$args` only containing a the contents of a third argument that is not visible in the method signature.

Now, how can this work at all – as I pointed out `walk()` is called only with one argument, so how can `$elements` and `$max_depth` be left out, without resulting in an error?

Comment: It's called with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), so the 1st 2 elements get assigned to the declared arguments `$elements` and `$max_depth`, leaving the third element (`$r` which is the original `$args`) to be assigned via `array_slice` to `$args`. Simple!

Comment: @bonger as an answer please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments, it's called with [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), so the 1st 2 elements get assigned to the declared arguments `$elements` and `$max_depth`, leaving the third element (`$r` which is the original `$args`) to be assigned via array_slice to `$args`. Eg

```
function wpse172812( $elements, $max_depth ) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    error_log("elements=$elements, max_depth=$max_depth, args=" . print_r( $args, true ));
    // elements=arg1, max_depth=arg2,
    // args=Array ( [0] => Array ( [menu] => my_id [menu_class] => my_class ) )
}
$args = array( 'arg1', 'arg2', array( 'menu' => 'my_id', 'menu_class' => 'my_class' ) );
call_user_func_array( 'wpse172812', $args );
```